# Oracle 12c Compare last_ddl_time on views

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of views in two schemas in which everything is equal except the last_ddl_time.

```
select owner, object_name, last_ddl_time
from all_objects
where object_type = upper('view')
and owner in ('SC1', 'SC2')
order by 2,1,3;
```

produces the correct data, but I would like the SQL to compare last_ddl_time and return data only if the last_ddl_time for SC1 is larger than last_ddl_time for SC2.

I have tried creating a sub-query that makes the comparisons, but cannot get the syntax worked out to produce the compared data.

The object is to find views updated in SC2 before the view of the same name was updated in SC1.

Any and all suggestions & insights appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an inline view (or a similar CTE) that finds the DDL time for each schema, e.g. using an aggregate and windowing clause, and the filter the results by comparing those values in the outer query:

```
select owner, object_name, last_ddl_time
from (
  select owner, object_name, last_ddl_time,
    max(case when owner = 'SC1' then last_ddl_time end)
      over (partition by object_name) as sc1_time,
    max(case when owner = 'SC2' then last_ddl_time end)
      over (partition by object_name) as sc2_time
  from all_objects
  where object_type = 'VIEW'
  and owner in ('SC1','SC2')
)
where sc1_time > sc2_time
order by 2,1,3;
```

You could also use this to show both DDL times side-by-side:

```
select object_name, sc1_time, sc2_time
from (
  select owner, object_name,
    max(case when owner = 'SC1' then last_ddl_time end)
      over (partition by object_name) as sc1_time,
    max(case when owner = 'SC2' then last_ddl_time end)
      over (partition by object_name) as sc2_time
  from all_objects
  where object_type = 'VIEW'
  and owner in ('SC1','SC2')
)
where sc1_time > sc2_time
and owner = 'SC1'
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure there are same views on both schemas I would go with simple inner join

```
with sc1 as (
     select owner, object_name, last_ddl_time
        from all_objects
        where object_type = 'VIEW' and owner = 'SC1'), 
     sc2 as (
     select owner, object_name, last_ddl_time
        from all_objects
        where object_type = 'VIEW' and owner = 'SC2')
    select sc1.object_name, sc1.last_ddl_time from sc1 inner join sc2
      on (sc1.object_name = sc.object_name)
    where sc1.last_ddl_time > sc2.last_ddl_time;
```

Comment: commas following last_ddl_time need to go away, but it works fine.. Thank you!!

Comment: @user761758 commas removed.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 12, you can use `match_recognize`. The example is from my copy of Oracle; I copied the SCOTT schema to my own (called INTRO), so we have a few objects to test on.

```
select object_type, object_name, scott_last_ddl_time, intro_last_ddl_time
from   all_objects
match_recognize (
  partition by object_type, object_name
  order     by last_ddl_time
  measures     s.last_ddl_time as scott_last_ddl_time,
               i.last_ddl_time as intro_last_ddl_time
  pattern      (s i)
  define       s as s.owner = 'SCOTT',
               i as i.owner = 'INTRO' and i.last_ddl_time > s.last_ddl_time
)
order by object_type, object_name, scott_last_ddl_time  -- ORDER BY is optional
;

OBJECT_TYPE OBJECT_NAME SCOTT_LAST_DDL_TIME INTRO_LAST_DDL_TIME
----------- ----------- ------------------- -------------------
INDEX       PK_DEPT     2016-10-05 18:18:34 2016-10-05 21:52:31
INDEX       PK_EMP      2016-10-05 18:18:34 2016-10-05 21:52:31
TABLE       BONUS       2016-10-05 18:18:35 2016-10-05 21:52:31
TABLE       DEPT        2016-10-05 18:18:34 2016-10-05 21:52:33
TABLE       EMP         2016-10-05 18:18:34 2016-10-05 21:52:34
TABLE       SALGRADE    2016-10-05 18:18:35 2016-10-05 21:52:31

 6 rows selecte
```

If the `last_ddl_time` were to be compared non-strict (`>=` rather than `>`), then you wouldn't even need the comparison in the definition of `i`, the comparison would be taken care by the `order by` clause in `match_recognize`.